# Create trigger that TRUNCATE child table after INSERT into parent table MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a child table that contains the following info

```
CREATE TABLE child_1(
  `Event` TEXT,
  `Event Description` TEXT)
```

I then have a parent table that contains similar information

```
CREATE TABLE parent_1(
  `Event` TEXT,
  `Event Description` TEXT)
```

I need help creating a trigger that will TRUNCATE my child table after inserting it into my parent table. I am receiving an error when running the below code.

For now I have written

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRUNCATE_child_1     
  AFTER DELETE ON child_1
  FOR EACH ROW     
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO parent_1 VALUES (child_1.`Event`, child_1.`Event Description`)
END
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @usagiMiyamoto The trigger statement I have written is not working. The trigger should ideally TRUNCATE the child table after the child table is inserted into the Parent table.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger tries to insert every remaining row of `child_1` into `parent_1` if any row from `child_1` is deleted...

---

What you seem to need is a stored procedure, that will make the insertion and the truncation in one step. Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE move_child_to_parent();
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO partner_1 (`Event`, `Event description`)
    SELECT `Event`, `Event description`
      FROM child_1;
  TRUNCATE child_1;
END;
```

Comment: thank you. I tried running this and I get an error saying child_1 is not a unique tables/alias . Do you know why this occurs ?